# Binary Search Tree Contains Method Java Parameters

Tags: java

I am confused about the contains method for my Binary Search Tree class.

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {

    if (o == null)
    {
        throw new NullPointerException("Null Items are not allowed in the tree");
    }


    if (root.item.equals(o))
    {
    return true;
    }
    return false;


}
```

Here is my header:

```
public class BSTreeSet<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Set<E>, CompareCount {


private Node root =null;
private int size;
private int compareCount;
```

The error I am receiving on the JUnit test:

```
public void testContains() {
    BSTreeSet<Integer> testSet = new BSTreeSet<Integer>( ); 
    testSet.clear( );
    testSet.add( 10);
    testSet.add( 20);
    testSet.add( 30);
    testSet.add( 40);
    testSet.add( 15);
    testSet.add( 25);
    testSet.add( 5);
    testSet.add( 1);

    assertTrue("contains must return true for the element 10", testSet.contains(10));
```

I am confused about how to search down the right and left side with the proper variables... I know this is almost the same question as before but I am stuck!

Comment: What do you mean by "When the interface creates this method"?

Comment: When I add the unimplemented methods it creates a default method that looks like the following:
    public boolean contains(Object arg0) {
  
  return false;

Comment: If your interface requires an Object parameter, you need to use that. But notice that the `contains` method within your question actually has **two** parameters.

Comment: For a complete description of your problem, you should include in your post the interface definition of the method `contains` as well as the fail you get in your JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

The abstract class `AbstractCollection<E>` or the interface `Collection<E>` in java.util define

```
public boolean contains(Object o)
```

which makes sense, considering that using the generic type E is an unnecessary constraint. (An implementation might want to permit a quite different type.)

Using `Node root` as an additional parameter is very likely not what is intended by the specification of your class via some interface. A tree's root node is a property of the Tree class and its implementation - whether it is indeed a Node of the Tree or something else - should remain hidden. Typically you call the test for the containment of an Object obj in a Tree tree as

```
if( tree.contains( obj ) ){ ... }
```

Finally, your implmentation isn't correct: if the thing you are looking for isn't equal to the root node (or some other node) you'll have to investigate the left or right subtree.